# SSH won't restart after reboot

Tags: ssh

After rebooting I can't restart my ssh. This is the ssh status

```
root@mx:/# systemctl status ssh.service
●ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Sat 2019-01-19 23:02:11 PST; 4s ago
  Process: 8986 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=255)

Jan 19 23:02:11 mx systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jan 19 23:02:11 mx systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 19 23:02:11 mx systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 19 23:02:11 mx systemd[1]: ssh.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 19 23:02:11 mx systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jan 19 23:02:11 mx systemd[1]: ssh.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 19 23:02:11 mx systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jan 19 23:02:11 mx systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 19 23:02:11 mx systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

Comment: More information would be needed.

Please edit and paste the result of the following command:

journalctl -b -xn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH Server stops working after reboot, caused by missing /var/run/sshd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109934/ssh-server-stops-working-after-reboot-caused-by-missing-var-run-sshd)