# Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell on Reboot

Tags: sshd

During reboot:

```
● sshd.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service; disabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-10-01 21:19:13 UTC; 23s ago
  Process: 1411 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS (code=exited, status=255)
  Process: 1247 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1411 (code=exited, status=255)

Oct 01 21:19:12 fhsuc1ifebpap01 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Oct 01 21:19:13 fhsuc1ifebpap01 sshd[1411]: error: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 fa
Oct 01 21:19:13 fhsuc1ifebpap01 sshd[1411]: error: Bind to port 22 on :: failed:
Oct 01 21:19:13 fhsuc1ifebpap01 sshd[1411]: fatal: Cannot bind any address.
Oct 01 21:19:13 fhsuc1ifebpap01 systemd[1]: sshd.service: Main process exited, c
Oct 01 21:19:13 fhsuc1ifebpap01 systemd[1]: sshd.service: Failed with result 'ex
Oct 01 21:19:13 fhsuc1ifebpap01 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell
```

If I kill all sshd processes, and restart sshd service it runs fine.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server error when I try to run apt-get or to install Ubuntu upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113607/failed-to-start-openbsd-secure-shell-server-error-when-i-try-to-run-apt-get-or-t) and also: [SSH Server stops working after reboot, caused by missing /var/run/sshd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109934/ssh-server-stops-working-after-reboot-caused-by-missing-var-run-sshd/1110843#1110843)

Comment: I've used that doc to get it working again, but on reboot, it fails to start. After a reboot now, I can "restart" and all is good. But this isn't practical after every reboot to do.