# Ubuntu 20.04 won't boot up

Tags: boot, command-line

I've been trying to open my Ubuntu OS on a SBC device but it won't boot up and also it won't open terminal and when I run F7 to see what happen, I got this result attached here. Please what do I have to do?

[image: ubuntu 20.04 screenshot]

Comment: That question has been asked many times. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113607/failed-to-start-openbsd-secure-shell-server-error-when-i-try-to-run-apt-get-or-t)

Comment: the link you post on here was for ssh troubleshooting, I need to know what is going on. Please see my attached photo

Comment: Has anyone come across the above issue before please?

Comment: Can you boot it into recovery mode?

Comment: no, it will not boot into recovery mode.

Comment: finally got a solution, had to repair the file system using gparted. it works fine now but make sure you back up your drive before repairing.Thanks