# SSH connection refused after upgrading

Tags: 16.04, ssh

After upgrading then rebooting my Ubuntu 16.04 server it's now impossible to connect with ssh anymore. 
This is what I get whenever I try to connect:

> ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xx.xx port 22: Connection refused

Note: I didn't modify the ssh settings or whatever during the upgrade.

What can I do ?