# SSH port 22 is closed after reboot from command?

Tags: server, ssh

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 installed natively, and everytime I reboot the system from command line using,

```
reboot
```

or

```
shutdown -r now
```

the default port for SSH is closed. To remediate that, I have to physically force reboot the system. This has never happened, so I cannot make any sense of that.

**Update**

Running shutdown & then physically turning on works,

```
shutdown -h now
```

Comment: How did you checked the port is closed? Can you open it in some way without reboot?

Comment: Using **nmap**, and then when I reboot it physically (because I cannot SSH to the system), the port opens and I can SSH to it.

Comment: Probably something breaks the normal start of the ssh server. Please check whether you are experience an issue as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/1109934/566421).

Comment: `journalctl /usr/sbin/sshd` will show you `sshd` log messages back to the Beginning-Of-Time. `journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/sshd` will show the current boot's messages,  `journalctl -b -1 /usr/sbin/sshd` the previous,etc. `journalctl --list-boots` is handy, too.